# Admin auto-refresh is interfering with Firebug -- how to prevent it?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, metabox

I'm developing a plugin that adds a metabox to the post editing page.

When I try to debug it with Firebug, about every 15 seconds the Firebug display refreshes as though the page has reloaded. This collapses the code tree and loses my place, so I have to start from scratch... and get where I want within 15 seconds.

I've disabled all plugins, so I assume this is standard WordPress behavior (version 4.0).

Is it possible to prevent this auto-refresh, or to otherwise make Firebug usable on the post editing page?

Comment: off-topic as this is a firebug bug/feature that have nothing to do with wordpress. That said, if you change the dom every 15 seconds you are most likely doing something wrong

Comment: @MarkKaplun Thanks for your comment. To clarify: this is on-topic because it's caused by an interaction between WordPress and Firebug; someone in a Firebug forum could equally say "Firebug is working as it should, so please ask WordPress people how to override the heartbeat". Using the default Twenty Fourteen theme without plugins (none of my code), the 15-second WordPress heartbeat still causes Firebug to refresh. I'm hoping someone can provide a WordPress-based solution, possibly a variable or wp-config setting that will slow down or temporarily disable the WordPress heartbeat.

Comment: but no one in the firebug team will say that because they should have a plan what to do when the dom is being refreshed every 15 seconds if it is wordpress or not. and I didn't see any place in which  heartbeat updates the dom in the way you describe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments, an alternative is to use the built-in Firefox debugger instead (Inspect Element (Q)) - it's very good (now) and is (almost completely) unaffected by the WP heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way around the problem, but it's a kludge, so I won't accept my own answer unless nobody has a "real" solution.

If I set a break-point in my JavaScript and do my investigation while it's paused, that prevents all future script from running, including whatever script is refreshing the page.

Comment: Use the built-in Firefox debugger instead (Inspect Element (Q)) - it's very good and is (almost completely) unaffected by the WP heartbeat.

Comment: @bonger +1 for the tip. I'm most comfortable with Firebug, but it looks like Inspect Element has come a long way since I last used it. Will try that if I can't find a good FB solution.

Comment: @bonger If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. It's a good alternative, and I've found nothing that solves the problem as easily in Firebug.

Comment: Kool, ta, will do!...